# How do I write the join in this query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have the following case :

Two tables their structure is like this :

[machine] (parent table):

```
machine_id (PK) | machine_name | desc
```

[machine_in_out] (child table):

```
id (PK) | machine_in_id | machine_out_id
```

Now I want to get the name of `machine_in_id`, `machine_out_id` through the parent table.

How to make this join?!

Comment: Could you describe your strucutre in a more common (understandable) manner?

Comment: Most people would call machine a lookup table rather than a parent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
Select  mio.ID, 
        m1.machine_name, 
        m2.machine_name
From    [machine_in_out] mio
Join    [machine] m1
        On  mio.machine_in_ID = m1.machineID
Join    [machine] m2
        On  mio.machine_out_ID = m2.machineID
```